# How to apply masking on datefield in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, flashbuilder4

How to apply masking on `datefield` in flex? 
like when i enter text in `datefield` it should be converted like `MM/DD/YYYY`

Comment: Manually parse the input. Not a date - throw a warning on screen.

Comment: @Vesper I wana know the event that is executed when user enter input text.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **`formatString`** property of the `DateField` in the `change` event

```
<mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.events.*;

                private function dateChanged(event:Event):void
                {
                    dateField1.formatString = "MM/DD/YYYY";
                }
            ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:DateField id="dateField1" change="dateChanged(event)" />
```

Comment: But the change method not dispatch when user input manually besides select date.

Comment: So you want to dispatch it while entering text??